# Conditional ISSET issue

Tags: php, forms, conditional-statements, isset

In a single product page, the product ID is assigned to the var `$productID`. The problem is when, staying in one of the fields of the form and push the ENTER key, the page crashes since the script can't find the ID again. So I would implement the script in the following way.

```
<?php
$product_id = $_GET['product_id'];
include '../sys/conn.php';
$risultato = mysqli_query ($conn, "

(mysql query)

") or die ("Query not valid: " . mysqli_error($conn));
mysqli_close($conn);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($risultato);
?>
```

That I implemented in order that if $_GET is not set properly, it is set to  13321 (example value).

```
<?php

$product_id = $_GET['product_id'];

if(!isset($_GET['product_id']){ 
$product_id='13321';
}else{ 
include '../sys/conn.php';
$risultato = mysqli_query ($conn, "
(mysql query)

") or die ("Query not valid: " . mysqli_error($conn));
mysqli_close($conn);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($risultato);
}
?>
```

The conditional clause looks like is not accepted and generates errors such like syntax or unexpected variables. Any help?

---VERSION 2----

```
<?php
$product_id = $_GET['product_id'];

if(!isset($_GET['product_id'])){ 
    $product_id='13321';}
    else 
{

include '../sys/conn.php';
$risultato = mysqli_query ($conn, "

(MYSQL Query)

") or die ("Query non valida: " . mysqli_error($conn));
mysqli_close($conn);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($risultato)

}
?>
```

And the error is: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/gest/pages/singolo_prodotto.php on line 66

Comment: Does `$_GET['product_id']` come from a form input? It will most likely always be _set_ if so.

Comment: Also, do you have an actual query that you haven't shown in your example code here? Just making sure.

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket on this line: `if(!isset($_GET['product_id']){ `

Comment: Hi, the product ID comes from the Products List Page with this : <a href="singolo_prodotto.php?product_id='.$row['id'].'">Link</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed bracket:

```
if(!isset($_GET['product_id']){
```

Should be

```
if(!isset($_GET['product_id'])){
```

Comment: Mitch, I implemented the syntax but it still give error on line 66 that is the closing brace parenthesis

Comment: Code you pasted have not 66 lines. I bet error is in file you includes.

Comment: You're right, the 66 line has no sense since it is an excerpt my post. However I resumed only the sql query, the rest is fully reported in the post.

Comment: Mitch, I implemented my original post with code in the part I marked ---VERSION 2--- that is the current one

Comment: Where is sys/conn.php file ?

Comment: It is the the script to get connection to the database. It is stored in a subfolder.

Comment: Paste it on pastebin or something like that

Comment: Mitch did you find something wrong in my conn.php file?

Comment: $row = mysqli_fetch_array($risultato) you are missing ";" at the end